# Is there a regex for a row of numbers in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create an if statement that checks a string for illegal arguments

```
String numbers;

    try {
        if (numbers.matches("0|1|2|3|4")) {

        } 
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    ...
```

Is there a way to shorten that regular expression, e.g. "0-4" (which doens't work)? I've read a bit about regex [here](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/) but it's mostly about checking the structure of a string, and not about specific values.

Edit:
I'm looking for a regular expression that excepts just one of those digits.

Comment: its `[0-4]` with brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten it to `[0-4]` (square brackets means a character set):

```
numbers.matches("[0-4]")
```

That will match each character separately though and find matches in a string that contains other characters too.

If you want to make sure that there is only one digit between 0 and 4, you can use:

```
numbers.matches("^[0-4]$")
```

Comment: But that would except the regex "021", right? I want it to just be one digit. Sorry for not being so clear about that.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to make it  check for only one digit.